# Creating dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a dynamically allocated array, that when filled, creates a new array large enough to hold everything and copies all the values from the old array to the new array. I do in my append function, which when called dynamically allocates a new array with tmp pointing to it, and then moves the values from arr[i] to tmp [i]. However, I'm wondering if I need to delete tmp when I'm done with it? Because when I try to print the contents of the array without deleting tmp, it prints just fine, but when I do delete tmp, things just start getting weird and the contents no longer print the way they should. Here's my code:

```
ArrayList::ArrayList(int initsize): last(0), size(initsize), origsize(initsize)
{
    arr = new int[size];
}

ArrayList::ArrayList() 
{
    last = 0;
    size = 16;
    origsize = 16;
    arr = new int[size];
}

void ArrayList::append(int value) 
{
    if (last<size) {
        arr[last] = value;
    }

    last++;

    if (last == size) {

        int* tmp = new int[size+origsize];
        int i = 0;

        for (i=0; i<(size+origsize); i++)
            tmp[i] = arr[i];

        size = size+origsize;
        arr = tmp;
        arr[last] = value;

        //delete tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just make sure you delete at the right place. Your comment deletes `tmp`, but I think you should delete `arr` right before the `arr=tmp` line.

Comment: ... I assume this is academic and therefore throwing the entire thing out in favor of a `std::vector<int>` is out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
for (i=0; i<(size+origsize); i++) {

        tmp[i] = arr[i];

    }
```

arr is of length 'size' but you are trying to access elements beyond it. It shall result in undefined behaviour.

IMO, you should not try to re-size an array in your program. If you want a dynamic sized container, use a std::vector instead.

EDIT: As others have pointed out, if this is for academic reason, then you can modify your code something like the following:

```
void ArrayList::append(int value) 
{
    if (last<size) {
        arr[last] = value;
        last++;
    } else { // last shall be equal to size.

        int* tmp = new int[size+origsize];
        int i = 0;

        for (i=0; i<(size); i++) // delete + originalsize
            tmp[i] = arr[i];

        size = size+origsize;
        int* newTemp = arr; // make a new pointer point to where arr was pointing
        arr = tmp;         // make arr point to where tmp was pointing.
        //tmp = newTemp; // You do not need this statement.
        arr[last] = value;
        last++;
        delete [] newTemp; // delete the old array memory block
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I would rather use that I'm sure (we haven't learned that in class) but our professor specifically wants us...to do this on our own like this, I guess to teach us some lesson that I do not understand. He doesn't like us using any functions that we didn't create ourselvs

Comment: I think he's trying to implement ArrayList, which under the hood just uses arrays and resizes them.

Answer (score 2):

Your arr is now tmp. I mean they both points to a new array. And you need to delete the old one. Do

```
int* old = arr;
arr = tmp;
delete [] old;
arr[last] = value;
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly..when you delete arr, you delete the old array. Then you ask tmp to point to what arr was pointing to..which at this point is nothing since arr was deleted...

Comment: So if I just do delete old, I'm simply deleting the pointer named old. But to delete the actual array old is pointing to, I need to do delete[] old?

Comment: also, can't I just do 
delete [] arr;
arr=tmp;
arr[last] = value;

Comment: I should probably @ people if I want a response

Comment: No, delete [] is just a proper way to delete arrays. Yes, you can just do it, I've just messed up in hurry.

Answer (score 0):

The new array is point to the old one.

So in your code(withou modifications) you cannot delete the arr

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should delete tmp because, since you've declared it as a pointer using the *. It will not be automatically deallocated once you leave the scope (leaving the next }), and will cause a memory leak. Helpful post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap#79936) about the pointer and how declaring it puts it on the heap and requires it to be manually deleted. 
Since you're trying to make a dynamic array here. I think you want arr to be the pointer, not tmp.
Check out [this c++ tutoriall](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `new` and `delete`, which is C-ish. In C++ you should be trusting existing facilities to handle memory for you. We could use `std::vector`, though it would thwart the exercise; instead I propose that we use `std::unique_ptr`.

```
class ArrayList {
public:
    ArrayList();

    explicit ArrayList(size_t i);

    void append(int i);

private:
    size_t last;                  // position to append to
    size_t size;                  // current size of the array
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> array; // actual array of data
}; // class ArrayList
```

*Note: rather than using `origsize`, we can double the capacity at each expansion, thus gaining "amortized constant" complexity for `append`.*

```
// We first need a creation function for raw memory:
std::unique_ptr<int[]> allocate(size_t n) {
    return std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[n]);
}

// Now, the default constructor
ArrayList::ArrayList(): last(0), size(16), array(allocate(size)) {}

// And the user constructor
ArrayList::ArrayList(size_t i): last(0), size(i), array(allocate(size)) {}
```

With this out of the way, let us focus on `append`:

```
void ArrayList::append(int e) {
    if (last >= size) { // need to reallocate
        std::unique_ptr<int[]> neo = allocate(size*2);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            neo[i] = array[i];
        }

        size *= 2;
        swap(neo, array);
    } // reallocation

    array[last] = e;
    ++last;
}
```

How does it differ from your code:

1. When copying from one array to another, I only copy `size` elements (you were reading out of bounds)
2. I do not handle memory manually, instead I defer memory handling to `std::unique_ptr`.
3. There is no need to re-allocate after you inserted `e` in `append`, you can just wait to have run out of place to do so.
4. Using amortized constant complexity for `append` is more efficient